# How can I animate or transition SVG paths with CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-path

I have created an SVG image in Adobe Illustrator which has the following code:

```html
<svg id="logo_top" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1440 1440" enable-background="new 0 0 1440 1440"
     xml:space="preserve" height="512px" width="512px">
  <g>
    <path id="path1" d="M1140.475,774.096c4.692,3.807,12.367,5.709,23.023,5.709c10.655,0,18.326-1.902,23.023-5.709
                                     c4.691-3.805,7.039-9.764,7.039-17.885c0-8.117-2.348-14.08-7.039-17.887c-4.697-3.805-12.368-5.707-23.023-5.707
                                     c-10.656,0-18.331,1.902-23.023,5.707c-4.697,3.807-7.04,9.77-7.04,17.887C1133.435,764.332,1135.777,770.291,1140.475,774.096z" />
    <path id="path2" d="M1140.475,716.163c4.693,3.806,12.367,5.708,23.023,5.708s18.326-1.902,23.023-5.708c4.691-3.806,7.039-9.764,7.039-17.886
                                     c0-8.117-2.348-14.08-7.039-17.886c-4.697-3.806-12.367-5.708-23.023-5.708s-18.33,1.902-23.023,5.708
                                     c-4.697,3.806-7.039,9.769-7.039,17.886C1133.436,706.399,1135.777,712.357,1140.475,716.163z" />
    <path id="path3" d="M1140.475,658.23c4.693,3.805,12.367,5.707,23.023,5.707s18.326-1.902,23.023-5.707c4.691-3.807,7.039-9.764,7.039-17.887
                                     c0-8.116-2.348-14.08-7.039-17.885c-4.697-3.807-12.367-5.709-23.023-5.709s-18.33,1.902-23.023,5.709
                                     c-4.697,3.805-7.039,9.769-7.039,17.885C1133.436,648.467,1135.777,654.424,1140.475,658.23z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

What I want to achieve is to have the topmost dot move upwards when I hover on the `SVG`. So far I have tried the following:

1. `transform: translate(0, 10px);`
2. `position: relative;` and `bottom: 10px;`
3. `margin-bottom: 10px;`
4. `padding-bottom: 10px;`

Unfortunately, none of the above has worked and I am now left curious as to why `svg` elements require such special treatment and don't work as every other "normal" HTML element.

I know that polygons can be animated using `animatetransform`. But it doesn't seem to work for me on paths too.

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                      attributeType="XML"
                      type="rotate"
                      from="0 60 70"
                      to="360 60 70"
                      dur="10s"
                      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

What is the property I have to change in order to move the topmost dot upwards?

Comment: You can't. The path points are not selectable with CSS. You need javascript

Comment: Ok @Paulie_D, I can use some JavaScript if that can make it work.

Comment: How can I do this with SMIL @RobertLongson?

Comment: Did you try `transform: translate(0, -10px)`? Notice you misspelled `transform` and translated in the positive Y direction.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it works! But how? Since I already tried that, even on the opposite side shouldn't it at least move down?

Comment: @AngelPolitis it doesn't work when you misspell "transform".

Comment: That is not the case, because I didn't copy-paste from my code. I only made the mistake here. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to manipulate the path points the use of JavaScript is required. The following code achieves the desired result:

```
$("#path1").css("transform", "translate(0, -100px)");
```